# Converting image from eps to pdf changes placement

Tags: floats

I'm finishing up the formatting of a document, and for compatibility reasons I converted an `.eps` image to `.pdf`. After doing so, the `figure*` it is inside is being forced to a full page at the end of the document. Any ideas why converting an image from `.eps` to `.pdf` would cause this change? Any suggestions on how to undo the change? (The figure should be on page 4, but is being pushed to page 7.) I'm using:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{screenshot}
  \caption{My caption here.}
\label{fig:screenshot}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `*.eps` and `*.pdf` verson of your image do have the same print size? This might depend on the conversion method/program

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The most likely cause is a problem with the image or the conversion. Can you make the `eps` and `pdf` versions available for download and add links here?

Comment: I used Apple's Preview application and its "Save as PDF..." option to convert to `.pdf`. I'll put the links up shortly.

Comment: No need to post the images - your suggestions pointed out the right answer - and the poor behavior of Apple's Preview application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ends up that Apple's Preview application opened and displayed the `.eps` file properly. If, at that point I choose to `Save...` the document everything is fine, and I get a correctly formatted `.pdf` file with correct margins, etc.

But, if I choose `Export as PDF...`, it exports and shows the `.pdf` on the screen properly. However, on disk the margins are much too large, meaning that the image won't typeset properly as described in my question. Strange behavior, to say the least, and something to be aware of when exporting files from `.eps` to `.pdf` in Apple's Preview application.